# NOT operator in string for Series.str.contains

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Is there a way I can assign a not operator within a string itself when using `Series.str.contains`? (Not with a `~` operator.) For example:

I want cat and dog but not fox.

```
srStr = 'cat|dog' # input
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animals' : ['cat','dog','fox','elephant']}) # cannot change
df.Animals.str.contains(srStr) # cannot change
```

I want to set up `srStr` such that the last line of the code outputs `[True,True,False,True]`.

I cannot use the `~` operator for inverting a temporary result because the code is already part of an architecture and **I am passing `srStr` as an input**.

Comment: Reopened because OP must use `Series.str.contains`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `srStr = '^(?!fox$)'` (negative lookahead).

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to extend this to multiple such inputs. E.g fox AND cat?

Comment: @DhruvMahajan `srStr = '^(?!(fox|cat)$)'`